# Group by object and count each unique occurrence in powershell

Tags: powershell, window

Group by "assigned Team "

```
echo $var | Group-Object -property "Assigned Team"
```

---

INPUT -

```
PS C:\Users\Bharath> echo $var

Assigned Team
--------------
Database Administration Team
Email Applications Team
Unix Administration Team
Storage Administration Team
Windows Administration Team
Email Applications Team
TSO Senior Manager Team
Advance Digital Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Unix Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Email Applications Team
Unix Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Windows Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Database Administration Team
Email Applications Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
IP Voice and Video Team
IP Voice and Video Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
IP Voice and Video Team
IP Voice and Video Team
IP Voice and Video Team
IP Voice and Video Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Email Applications Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Unix Administration Team
Network Administration Team
Network Administration Team
```

INPUT -

```
PS C:\Users\Bharath> echo $var | group

Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    1 Microsoft.PowerShell.C...{Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData}
    1 Microsoft.PowerShell.C...{Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData}
  212 Microsoft.PowerShell.C... {Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData, Microsoft.PowerShell...
    1 Microsoft.PowerShell.C... {Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData}
    1 Microsoft.PowerShell.C... {Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData}

PS C:\Users\Bharath> $var.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Comment: Does not `echo $var | group` fits your needs?

Comment: o/p - Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    1 Microsoft.PowerShell.C... {Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData}
    1 Microsoft.PowerShell.C... {Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData}
  212 Microsoft.PowerShell.C... {Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData, Microsoft.PowerShell...
    1 Microsoft.PowerShell.C... {Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData}
    1 Microsoft.PowerShell.C... {Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData}

Comment: Please help me with this.

Comment: Please add the output of `echo $var | group` in your question (you can edit it), I can't understand it reading your comment.

Comment: I have updated the question with o/p. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3626342 add the output of this command: `$var.gettype()`

Comment: PS C:\Users\Bharath> $var.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

Comment: It seems that `var` is not an array of strings. I suggest you to save this content as a file and then group it. Try this: `echo $var > result.txt; cat result.txt | group`

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, $var contains formatted objects. Result of command:

```
foo | format-table 'Assigned Team'
```

... or anything to that effect.

`Format-*` should be avoided if you need to group/ sort/ filter objects.